# Visio 2010 - Where is Set Display Options

Tags: microsoft-visio

In visio 2003 you had the option Set display option when you right clicked on an object, in this menu I had the possibility of choosing Calculated Area..... Where is the similar function in 2010, anybody know this ??

Answer (score 0):

It is still available from some shapes, such as the Space shape, and most of those on the Walls, Doors and Windows stencil

Comment: Can you please add more specific information in your answer so user can understand it easily?